# Como fazer o file_exists procurar na pasta correta?

Tags: php

Estou testando se um arquivo existe assim:

```
if (file_exists('assets/img/items/'. $currentLocation['id'] .'c.jpg')){
    $galleryItem .= '<img src="assets/img/items/'. $currentLocation['id'] .'c.jpg" alt="">';
}
```

A questão é que o arquivo PHP que está fazendo essa consulta está em `assets/external/` então ele não acha o arquivo.

Como fazer pra ele procurar na pasta correta?

Abraços.

Comment: Você pode utilizar `..` para voltar um diretório, o caminho ficaria `../img/items/`

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comentario do @Denis Rudnei de Souza está correto. Entretanto você pode adicionar um pouco mais de precisão (evitar que em inclusões multiplas de arquivos, o diretorio corrente mude acidentalmente) usando a constante `__DIR__` e a função `realpath()`.

A constante [**DIR**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php) vai retornar o diretorio do script atualmente em execução e a função [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.realpath.php) vai transformar caminhos relativos (../pasta1/../a.php) em caminho absoluto.

Então aplicando à sua situação fica:

```
$caminho = 'assets/img/items/'. $currentLocation['id'] .'c.jpg';
if (file_exists(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../' . $caminho))){

}
```